# Kernel 4.10/4.12 with AMDGPU-PRO?

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, amd-graphics, proprietary

Is it possible to use AMDGPU-PRO driver with a newer Kernel under Ubuntu 16.04?

I couldn't find much information, sorry if I missed something.

So I converted my friend to linux. Since **Linux Mint 18.2** was released yesterday and it's based on Ubuntu, I installed it for him with **kernel 4.10**.

He got a **XFX Fury**. I tried installing the driver from AMD (**AMDGPU-PRO** for Ununtu 16.04) but after rebooting, I got black screen with an underscore (not blinking). Tried with kernel 4.8, 4.10, 4.12.

Rebooting in recovery mode, I found out there is an error with the display in xorg.log. Trying to boot with **nomodeset** works in **software rendering mode**.

I reinstalled Linux and now everything is running perfectly without this driver, but Overwatch need a videocard installed :P. (Running kern. 4.10)

I personally have an old graphic card (GTX 580) which runs beautifully under **Kernel 4.12**, released yesterday, with both closed-source driver and **nouveau**.

I was wondering why the AMD driver wasn't working. Unfortunatly I don't remember the exact error message - but I'll try to find the same message ont he internet and update this question. In the mean time I though maybe someone had a solution.

Thanks to anyone how may have some tips for us!

Cheers!

Comment: This site is only for official Ubuntu flavors. For Linux Mint, please ask on [the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Why bother with amdgpu-pro anyway? Fury and Fury X work just fine with the open source drivers.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: AMDGPU-PRO 17.30 supports 4.10+ kernels.

AFAIK, at the moment, there's no support for 4.9+ kernels coming from AMD. Since I was having the same issue, I had to switch to the normal amdgpu module. For the moment it works pretty well, I suggest to give it a try.

Here's some info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU

Sorry for not giving you a proper answer anyway.

Comment: Nah it's alright - thanks bud! The issue is Overwatch need a proper driver for the GPU in order to play in Wine. Thansk for your answer I couldn't find this anywhere! So I guess if I use Kernel 4.87 I can use the pro driver? Thanks!!

Comment: There's a new version of AMDGPU-PRO drivers (17.30) but it's still not compatible with the 4.10+ kernels. Actually I'm adding a new comment here only to suggest a read: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amdgpu-1730-radeonsi&num=1

Comment: Thansk! I'll read ;)